# Exchange Web Services -- Wrong .Net Version

Tags: exchangewebservices, assemblyversions

I am confused. I downloaded the latest version of EWS, but it is complied against .net 2.0.

My project is in 4.0 and the two won't work together. Surely I am making a dumb mistake. Can someone tell me what I am doing?

The warning I get from the class library that uses it is 
"referenced assembly Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices could not be resolved because of dependency on System.Web version 4.0.0.0"

I added that assembly, but got the same error message.

I think it is something to do with versions, but I feel like I am back in the DLL hell days. Any suggestions from anyone?